# Xcode failing to compile SnapKit library

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to use the "SnapKit" library for my project. Initially Xcode tried to compile all my files as Objective-C instead of Swift files but I added the `inherited` flag to the `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT` setting in Build Options and updated my pods to fix those compilation errors.

However I am still getting the following errors:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a problem with the SnapKit library?

Here is the project: https://github.com/vroomvsr/SnapKit-Error I am using SnapKit version 0.21.0

UPDATE ONE: It seems to work if I set the SnapKit version to 0.19.0 instead of 0.21.0

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the project using cmd+shift+K on xcode and rebuild it